# Why do i need to use background color on Grid in order to make button event work?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Why Grid, StackPanel etc. needs to have background in order to make MouseDown event work properly? If i don't set background then events that are connected to clicking mouse buttons won't trigger at all. After setting background to even transparent color it starts working properly.

What is the purpose of that solution? Is there something going on 'behind' the scene that i don't know about? Does Background setting change more than just background?

Comment: The real question is why are you doing `MouseDown` stuff in `Panel`s to begin with. That's what Buttons (and other non-`Panel`-based UI elements) are for. Post the relevant XAML and a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: Take a look at this article on MSDN: [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).

Comment: @HighCore: Seems unnecessary to question this. I can think of at least one valid use case: the developer is creating a window without a title bar, but he wants to allow the user to drag it around by clicking anywhere on the window. I've seen this a lot with splash screens.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set a background, you will click *through* it, the element below it (probably the Window) will get the events.

Comment: Does that explain why `transparent` works? And `Color` is a structure, so it must have a value. So how can you _not_ provide a value?

Comment: Background is not a Color, but a Brush. The brush constructor from XAML will create one of the [Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.brushes(v=vs.110).aspx) if you give it a color name. So passing Transparent will create a Solid brush with Transparent color, not setting the Background will mean you have no brush at all.

Comment: @Clemens, ah, in WinForms it's a Color. I did not know it changed in WPF.

Comment: @gunr2171 You can't even speak of a *change*, since WPF is completely unrelated to WinForms.

Comment: I understand... but why Brushes has any correlations with events?

Comment: @morfidon `why Brushes has any correlations with events` - Read the `Hit Testing` article linked in Clemens' comment above.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to click through is to set the background color's `A` property to 0%. You can do that in the Properties of the controls, click on the Background, you will see R,G,B,A. Give A a zero

```
<Button Content="OK" Background="#00000000" Width="150"/>
```

Now you can have a transparent color and capture all events (not click through).

Note, originally I set the color to Black (R=0, G= 0, B= 0). Chaning the A, will change the original color to HEX notation, but it doesn't matter as you can pick any color and make it look transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it comes as a result of premise that user won't expect an element to be clicked if it's not visible on the screen.

"Empty" space should not react.

Of course there are exceptions, like list box item, where you *do* want a reaction even if you didn't actually clicked on a letter, but in between them. There, the template of list box item, has a transparent border to catch mouse events even if user misses the "right" target.

So basically, WPF gives you a mechanism to control what is hit test visible and what's not - and, without affecting behavior of children items. And it's only a `Background="Transparent"` away.